# Why does my work file work locally, but not on my webhosting server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, war, web-hosting

I developed a website and got a Tomcat account on Dailyrazor. My website runs fine when I start Tomcat from the command line and stick my war file in Apache's webapps folder. I access it by `http://localhost:8080/dkashtanartportfolio/`.

Now should it be as easy as dropping the war in my webapps folder on my DailyRazor Tomcat server? I expect to be able to access my website via `http://www.<domain-name>.com/<war-file-name>/`, which should look like `http://www.dkartportfolio.com/dkashtanartportfolio/`

I get a 404 error and I do not know why? Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you looked at the tomcat logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the DailyRazor accounts don't allow automatic deploy. So after uploading war you need to restart Tomcat. I use shell to execute tomcat_manage stop, followed by tomcat_manage start.
You may also be able to request restart by opening a help ticket.

For some reason, my accounts expect war's to be in public_html and not webapps. I have an old account so they may have changed the way new accounts work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look carefully into tomcat/conf/server.xml and make sure that you've specified correct path to app folder. Also you need to keep in mind that if you have shared tomcat you need to unpack your war file before requesting tomcat restart - it won't unpack automatically.